# trying to save Datastore data in a csv file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

In an application I'm using Google App Engine,And in the servlet I'm writing my logic where I save my data in datastore in the form of entity.

*I'm trying to save the data in a csv file...any inputs on this context will be appreciated.*

```
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    request.setAttribute("name", name);
    Key key=KeyFactory.createKey("name_param",name);
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    request.setAttribute("email", email);
    String date = request.getParameter("date");
    request.setAttribute("date", date);

    Entity entity=new Entity("key", key);
    entity.setProperty("parameter",name);
    entity.setProperty("email",email);
    entity.setProperty("date", date);

    DatastoreService datastore= DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    datastore.put(entity);
```

any idea for this....how to save it in a csv file..

Comment: do you have an actual question?

Comment: ACtually I want to save the Datastore data in a csv file,...so any inputs on this regards.

Comment: Is there any CSV library specifically you would like to use but having trouble with?

Comment: In an CSV file in the datastore, blobstore or locally?

Comment: If II want to store in a blobstore,how can I achieve this...?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to save a file in app engine, you have to use the blobstore, google cloud service or google drive. 
The blobstore is part of app engine. It is easy to download csv files from the blobstore.

Comment: Writing files: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore